# required if validation with email adress

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5, requiredfieldvalidator, laravel-validation

I am trying to validate one paypal id field based on payment option selected.

If payment option selected paypal then paypal_id must be present and type of email id. 
If payment option is credit then paypal id is not required.

```
$rule = [
            "paypal_id" => "required_if:payment-option,paypal|email"
        ];
```

But it gives me error ***"The paypal id must be a valid email address"***
When i select credit option.
The paypal payment option works perfectly.

Any suggestions will helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$rules = [/*... all rules except paypal_id ...*/];

if ($request->input("payment-option") == "paypal") {
    $rules["paypal_id"] =  "required|email";
}

$this->validate($request, $rules);
```

Comment: Yes This is small logic change which i already implemented but i want solution in single rule array.
If it is not possible then we will go for this.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$rule = [
        "paypal_id" => "sometimes|required_if:payment-option,paypal|email"
    ];
```